# How to redirect to page in the root directory from any internal page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

If I have page located for example in

```
http://hostname.com/website_folder/page1.aspx
```

and from page in internal folder, I want to redirect to the above page
For example from these pages:

```
http://hostname.com/website_folder/folder1/folder2/page2.aspx
```

or

```
http://hostname.com/website_folder/folder1/folder2/folder3/page2.aspx
```

Comment: you need to implement BeginRequest() method in global.asax and implement your custom logic to handle your internal folder navigation

Comment: Response.redirect is the way. have you checked following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741131/file-paths-in-asp-net . It handles the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Response.Redirect(your url); in your code behind page. 
 if you like to know more read here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903

Answer (score 0):

I assume whenever the request comes for the below urls

`http://hostname.com/website_folder/folder1/folder2/page2.aspx`
`http://hostname.com/website_folder/folder1/folder2/folder3/page2.aspx`

you want to perform a permanent redirect to `http://hostname.com/website_folder/page1.aspx`.

This can be achieved by `URL Mapping/Rewrite`

There are several [`approaches explained by Scott Guthrie`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) and also check [How to specify url mappings in ASP.NET 4.0 when parameters are involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636087/how-to-specify-url-mappings-in-asp-net-4-0-when-parameters-are-involved)